# How to get probability from predictions using GeneralizedLinearRegression model using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logistic-regression

I'm newbie to machine-learning and I was trying to implement binomial family of GeneralizedLinearRegression model using spark.

I tried this,

```
val trainingData = sparkSession.read.format("libsvm").load("trainingData.txt")
val testData = sparkSession.read.format("libsvm").load("testData.txt") 
val glr = new GeneralizedLinearRegression().setFamily("binomial").setLink("logit").setRegParam(0.3).setMaxIter(10)
val glrModel = glr.fit(trainingData)
model.transform(testData).show()
```

For my testData, I got my prediction value as 1.0E-16. And when I'm using LogisticRegression, it gives probability(0.765394663) and prediction(0.0) value.

I want to know,

1. How to predict classes using GeneralizedLinearRegression from prediction value. Should I find classes from prediction value by using a threshold value ?
2. How to find probability of the predicted value ?